# Converting RGB565 to RGB888 and back

Tags: java, opengl

I am using 16 bit colors. When I convert the color to rgb888 (8bits per color) and then back to rgb565 (5 bits for red, 6 for green and 5 for blue) I get a slightly darker/grayer image, even when no operations performed on the color.

Below are my functions:

```
private static Vector3 col = new Vector3();
public static Vector3 ShortToRGB888( short color )
{
    float r = (float)((color & 0xF800) >> 8);
    float g = (float)((color & 0x07E0) >> 3);
    float b = (float)((color & 0x001F) << 3);

    col.set(r, g, b);
    return col;
}

public static short RGB888ToShort( Vector3 col )
{
    col.clamp(0f, 255f);
    int result = (((int)col.x) << 8) & 0xF800;
    result |= (((int)col.y) << 3) & 0x07E0;
    result |= (((int)col.z) >> 3) & 0x001F;
    return (short)result;
}
```

What can be the problem? As I cannot find any problems with the bitshifting, after having looked at a similar question here: 
[Why does converting RGB888 to RGB565 many times cause loss of colour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11007997/why-does-converting-rgb888-to-rgb565-many-times-cause-loss-of-colour)

I am beginning to suspect there is something going on in the conversion to and from float.

**Edit:**

```
 short orig = data[tx][ty][tz];  // 16 bit short
 Vector3f color = ColorConversion.ShortToRGB888(orig);
 short ne = ColorConversion.RGB888ToShort(color);

 if (ne != orig) {
     ErrorHandler.log("Orig: " + orig + " New: " + ne);
 }

 Yields the following mismatches:

Canvasland: CL-ERROR - Orig: 23900 New: 19608
Canvasland: CL-ERROR - Orig: 23864 New: 21750
Canvasland: CL-ERROR - Orig: 23831 New: 21750
Canvasland: CL-ERROR - Orig: 23742 New: 19449
Canvasland: CL-ERROR - Orig: 23870 New: 19545
Canvasland: CL-ERROR - Orig: 23768 New: 21687
Canvasland: CL-ERROR - Orig: 23707 New: 21561
Canvasland: CL-ERROR - Orig: 23802 New: 21656
Canvasland: CL-ERROR - Orig: 23549 New: 21402
Canvasland: CL-ERROR - Orig: 23165 New: 21084
Canvasland: CL-ERROR - Orig: 23069 New: 20988
Canvasland: CL-ERROR - Orig: 22395 New: 15796
Canvasland: CL-ERROR - Orig: 22223 New: 20142
Canvasland: CL-ERROR - Orig: 23679 New: 19386
Canvasland: CL-ERROR - Orig: 23292 New: 21211
Canvasland: CL-ERROR - Orig: 22515 New: 18063
Canvasland: CL-ERROR - Orig: 23834 New: 21655
Canvasland: CL-ERROR - Orig: 23711 New: 19418
Canvasland: CL-ERROR - Orig: 22975 New: 20893
Canvasland: CL-ERROR - Orig: 22487 New: 15922
Canvasland: CL-ERROR - Orig: 23709 New: 19449
Canvasland: CL-ERROR - Orig: 23643 New: 21529
Canvasland: CL-ERROR - Orig: 22362 New: 15796
Canvasland: CL-ERROR - Orig: 23770 New: 21624
Canvasland: CL-ERROR - Orig: 22478 New: 18156
Canvasland: CL-ERROR - Orig: 23768 New: 21687
Canvasland: CL-ERROR - Orig: 23643 New: 21529
Canvasland: CL-ERROR - Orig: 23103 New: 20989
Canvasland: CL-ERROR - Orig: 23768 New: 21687
Canvasland: CL-ERROR - Orig: 23705 New: 21624
Canvasland: CL-ERROR - Orig: 23673 New: 21592
Canvasland: CL-ERROR - Orig: 23578 New: 21497
Canvasland: CL-ERROR - Orig: 23514 New: 21433
Canvasland: CL-ERROR - Orig: 22525 New: 15797
Canvasland: CL-ERROR - Orig: 23870 New: 19545
Canvasland: CL-ERROR - Orig: 23801 New: 21687
Canvasland: CL-ERROR - Orig: 23614 New: 19386
Canvasland: CL-ERROR - Orig: 23037 New: 20956
Canvasland: CL-ERROR - Orig: 23518 New: 19323
Canvasland: CL-ERROR - Orig: 23390 New: 21275
```

Comment: Are you sure this isn't due to the loss of precision? RGB565 can't store as wide of a range as RGB888 can.

Comment: running `RGB888ToShort(ShortToRGB888())` across all shorts produce the input, so your floating point conversions appear to be working fine.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo He's converting a 565 color to 888 and back, so there is no precision to be lost.

Comment: @vandale: That's a good idea, I'll run a test across all shorts as well. To clarify to others; I am using a 16 bit color as input, so no bits should be lost.

Comment: I've added my test results, there seem to be definite differences between input and output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The function clamp does not do what I expect it to do.

```
col.clamp(0f, 255f);
```

I will change it to have it using Math.min and Math.max.

Answer (score 0):

You will naturally lose the lowermost bits when converting RGB888 to RGB565:

Converting back and forth, has the same effect as simply masking out the bits that don't exist in the RGB565 format: RGB888 &= 0xF8FCF8. There is clearly a loss of information there (naturally).

(When I say lower 3 bits, I mean the red/blue channel, substitute with 2 for the green channel)

Dropping the 3 lower bits darkens the color channel (at most) by 7/256, thats rougly 1/32 and usually quite enough to be perceived when seeing the orginal color and the reconstructed color side by side on screen. In pictures with fine gradients it will also often introduce visible banding effects (the gradient becoming a set of clearly distinguishable regions).

Since the loss depends on the actual values of each channel, there is also possibly a change in tone because each channel is affected differently depending on the state of the lower 3 bits.

Comment: That doesn't apply however I would think, as the input color starts off as 16 bits so naturally doesn't even need those lower bits. Those missing bits shouldn't matter then, should they?

Comment: @RobotRock Maybe, maybe not. You don't really say where you're getting the "original" from (and what you're comparing to what). But since you wrote "image", I suspect its from a file, which would most likely be RGB888.

Comment: I've added a piece of code that shows it. I am really using true 16 bits color as source. The code in my original post (added) shows there is something wrong with the code too, as the result should be the same as the input.